# .NET HTTPS request - Post Data to login to site

Tags: c#, .net, http, https, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a service to login to an online banking website and download a user's latest transaction information.

I'm building it in .NET/C# and I'm trying to follow the example I'm seeing in another post on how to do this...
[.NET HTTP POST Method - Cookies issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151576/net-http-post-method-cookies-issue)

But I can't seem to get the example to work.

The site that I'm trying to log into is...
http://www.communityamericacu.com/

Here is what I've come up with so far...

```
public void RetrieveTransactions()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://secureaccess.cacu.com/accountlink/SignOn/SignOn.aspx");
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            writer.Write("user=****&PIN=****&BankFolder=Banking&BrandID=1&BrandFolder=cacu&BrandType=R&screenwidth=&screenheight=&RemoteLogin=N&ExitURL=&UserJavaPlatForm=Win32&UserJavaBrowser=Netscape&UserJavaVersion=5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F536.11+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F20.0.1132.47+Safari%2F536.11&UserJavaCodeName=Mozilla&UserJavaColorDepth=32&UserJavaColors=4294967296&UserJavaCurrentResolution=1600x900&UserJavaMaxResolution=1600x870&UserJavaEnabled=Yes&UserJavaAAFonts=No&UserJavaPlugins=+Remoting+Viewer+Native+Client+Chrome+PDF+Viewer+Shockwave+Flash+Shockwave+Flash+Adobe+Acrobat+Microsoft+Lync+2010+Meeting+Join+Plug-in+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+Microsoft+Office+2010+Microsoft+Office+2010+Google+Update+NVIDIA+3D+Vision+NVIDIA+3D+VISION+Java%28TM%29+Platform+SE+7+U5+Java+Deployment+Toolkit+7.0.50.255+Shockwave+for+Director+Silverlight+Plug-In+Remoting+Viewer+Native+Client+Chrome+PDF+Viewer+Shockwave+Flash+Shockwave+Flash+Adobe+Acrobat+Microsoft+Lync+2010+Meeting+Join+Plug-in+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+QuickTime+Plug-in+7.7.2+Microsoft+Office+2010+Microsoft+Office+2010+Google+Update+NVIDIA+3D+Vision+NVIDIA+3D+VISION+Java%28TM%29+Platform+SE+7+U5+Java+Deployment+Toolkit+7.0.50.255+Shockwave+for+Director+Silverlight+Plug-In&UserJavaUTCOffset=5");
        }
    }

    using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But this is the response I get...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>@ccountLink Error</title>
</head>
<body>
An error occurred.
</body>
</html>
```

Which is not what I get when I try to log into the site, even with an incorrect username and password.

This stuff is all a little over my head at this point.  Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds fishy. It may not be possible either due to ViewState validation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bank checks additional fields of HTTP request, such as User-Agent (i.e. browser) and when it cannot find them it gives errors? Try to add at least user agent (there is an example at the question that you've linked to). Maybe you would also have to add other fields. You can see complete list here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields