# how to call php script inside a java class?

Tags: php, android

A web application has a php script that adds tasks to a ticket (every ticket has no or several tasks), and I want to call this script from my class (ConnectionPost) just like if I was using a browser.
here's the code of ConnectionPost:

```
import ...

public class ConnectionPost {

 CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
 CountDownLatch latch2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();;
 HttpPost httpPost;
 HttpResponse reponce;
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
 BasicHttpContext myHttpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
 BasicCookieStore myCookieStore  =  new BasicCookieStore();
 HttpResponse loginResponce;
 String cook;

 public void makeConn(){




     httpPost = new HttpPost("http://169.254.101.101:80/front/tickettask.form.php");

    // adding task parameters to httpPost 

     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", "tache ajouté post android"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tickets_id", "7"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("taskcategories_id", "1"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", "1"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("is_private", "0"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("actiontime", "60"));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("add", "ajouter"));


    // define  cookieStore

     myHttpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, myCookieStore);

    //calling login() to log in 
     login();


     try {
        // setting headers


         httpPost.setHeader("Referer", "http://169.254.101.101/front/ticket.form.php?id=7");
         httpPost.setHeader("Origin","http://169.254.101.101");



        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


            Thread t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     try {
                         reponce = client.execute(httpPost,myHttpContext);
                         Log.d("makeConn excution de la req task","succés");
                        latch2.countDown();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        Log.d("makeConn excution de la req",e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("makeConn IOexception",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

             };
             t.start();
             try {
                latch2.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("latch login exception", e.getMessage());
            }

             //======================  display response
             if(reponce != null){




                    StatusLine status = reponce.getStatusLine();
                    int codeStatus = status.getStatusCode();
                    if(codeStatus != 200){
                        Log.d("statusCode", codeStatus+"");


                    }

                    else{

                        HttpEntity corps = reponce.getEntity();
                        InputStream is;
                        try {
                            is = corps.getContent();
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                            String r;
                            while((r = br.readLine()) != null){

                                s.append(r);
                            }

                            Log.d("Login succées",s.toString());
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            Log.d("illegal  makeConn excep", e.getMessage());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d("illegal makeConn IOexcep", e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
            }
            else{
                Log.d("reponse login", "null");
            }


     }
     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.d("makeConn conversion de la liste",e.getMessage());
        }


 }   


 public void login(){

     final HttpPost loginRequest  = new HttpPost("http://169.254.101.101:80/login.php");
     List<NameValuePair> loginValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
     loginValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("noAuto", "1"));
     loginValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_name", "glpi"));
     loginValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_password", "glpi"));

     try {

         Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 try {
                    loginRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFromEntity()loginValuePairs);
                    loginRequest.setHeader("Referer","http://169.254.101.101")
                    loginResponce = client.execute(loginRequest,myHttpContext);
                    latch1.countDown();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

         };
         t.start();
         try {
            latch1.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("latch login exception", e.getMessage());
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("login protocol  ecx", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("login IOExc", e.getMessage());   
        }


 }
}
```

The login() method returns a javascript file:

```
06-01 13:03:27.518: D/Login succées(3801):
--------------------------------------------            
NomNav = navigator.appName;            
if (NomNav=='Konqueror') {               
window.location='/index.php?error=1';            
} else {              
window.location='/index.php?error=1';          
}
```

according to index.php, this page will display the following message:
" YOU MUST ACCEPT COOKIES TO REACH THIS APPLICATION "

However, the makeConn() method returns a javascript file redirecting to (login.php), authentication page, just like if I wasn't logged in!

Comment: Wel first you are not adding the `loginValuePairs` to your login request.

Comment: sorry. I updated the code,  but I still having the same problem.

Comment: You must accept cookies to begin with. To be able to login. Your login failed. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151576/net-http-post-method-cookies-issue And search for further info.